# No solution, I still have this : "ng : command not found"

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

so far I managed to run `ng serve`, but since 4 or 5 days I can not, to solve the problem I tried everything that is proposed as a solution on the net but nothing works...

That's why I sincerely need your help !
How can I refurbish everything to make sure it will work ?

**package.json :**
`{
  "name": "cli-src",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}`

For info, I'm on WINDOWS.

Thank you very much who will try to help me !

Comment: You need to provide specific code and details of your error message.

Comment: Have you try: 

`npm uninstall @angular/cli -g` and `npm cache clean` and `npm install @angular/cli -g`

Comment: when I do : `npm cache clean` I've got :
`npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     C:\Users\bmmi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-19T20_37_50_555Z-debug.log`

Comment: use the `--force` switch

Comment: check if `ng`  is in `node_modules\.bin`  . if it is there and you still get this error. install it globally with `npm install -g <package-name>`

Comment: When I do thas : `$ npm install -g @angular/cli`
I've got that :

`C:\Users\myname\.npm-global\ng -> C:\Users\myname\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
+ @angular/cli@1.4.8
updated 1 package in 21.745s
`

Comment: and for : `$ npm install -g -f @angular/cli`
I've got :
`npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
C:\Users\myname\.npm-global\ng -> C:\Users\myname\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
+ @angular/cli@1.4.8
updated 1 package in 25.478s
`

Comment: running `ng` from the command line does it spit out error ?

Comment: when I run `ng` I've got only : `bash: ng: command not found`

Comment: since you say `ng` is in `node_modules\.bin\`  in your package.json file the "ng" section do this "ng":  `.\node_modules\.bin\ng` . then do `npm run ng`. bash ? if it does not work change the backwards slashes to forward slashes

Comment: now I've that :
`npm ERR! file C:\Users\myname\Desktop\viteuf_CRUD_angular-php\angular2_crud_php_mysql-master\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token . in JSON at position 106 while parsing near '...g": ".\node_modules\.bin\ng",
npm ERR!     "start...'
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\myname\Desktop\viteuf_CRUD_angular-php\angular2_crud_php_mysql-master\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
[...]
`

Comment: `[...]
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-19T20_57_23_450Z-debug.log`

Comment: show us your package.json file via your post

Answer (score 2):

1) Ensure that you have the Angular cli installed by typing this at the command line: `ng -v`

2) Ensure you are in the folder containing the `package.json` file. To confirm, navigate to the folder you are using and list the files.

3) Open the `package.json` file and ensure it has a scripts section with the appropriate scripts defined.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

4) Ensure you have installed all of the packages for the application. To confirm, ensure that there is a `node_modules` folder at the same location as the `package.json` file. To be absolutely sure, navigate to the folder containing the `package.json` file and type `npm install`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I've got `ng : command not found` when I do `ng -v` .
I do all of your recommandation, this project worked 4 days ago, I want to delete all and restart but I don't not what I can delete.

Comment: It sounds like you no longer have the Angular CLI. Looks like someone else above is walking you through how to fix that.

Comment: @DeborahK he uses windows, i think he should specify the absolute path to `ng` i.e "ng": "node_modules\.bin\ng"

Comment: No. I use windows and absolute path is not needed if installed using the -g flag.

Comment: I've `ng` in node_modules/.bin/ but it's not recognized

Comment: If you correctly installed the Angular CLI globally as per the instructions, it should appear here: C:\Users\bmmi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: I don't have \ng directory in C:\Users\bmmi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules , do you know why ?

Comment: It wouldn't be `ng`, it would be `angular-cli`, which is the name of the tool.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't have angular-cli, I only have these directory :
`cordova/  pm2/               react-native-fbsdk/        realm/      yarn/
ionic/    react-native-cli/  react-native-git-upgrade/  undefined/`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue using Bash. Consider NOT using Bash with windows. (I don't).

If you need to continue to use Bash, see the extended set of information here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5021

If you are on Windows:

1) Right-click on the start button in the lower left corner and select `Run`.

2) Select to open `cmd`, which may already be the default.

3) Click OK. This should open a command prompt.

4) Type the commands specified earlier, one at a time:

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
npm cache --force clean
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

5) Type `ng -v` and you should now have the CLI appropriately installed.

Comment: I can use nodejs command prompt, but can you tell me which command I would have to use

Comment: I have that when I do : `npm cache clean` :

`npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bmmi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-19T21_24_15_481Z-debug.log`

Comment: use `npm cache --force clean`

Comment: for `npm install @angular/cli -g` :

`C:\Users\bmmi\.npm-global\ng -> C:\Users\bmmi\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\bmmi\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js
Cached binary found at C:\Users\bmmi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3\win32-x64-48_binding.node
> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\bmmi\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js
[...]`

Comment: `[...]
> node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\bmmi\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js
Binary found at C:\Users\bmmi\.npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
+ @angular/cli@1.4.8
added 786 packages and updated 1 package in 65.285s`

Comment: AND FOR : `ng -v` :

`module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\bmmi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3`